# Expected Number of Distinct Lottery Tickets

Tags: probability

Suppose 50 million people each buy one quick-pick lottery ticket where there are 300 million different lottery tickets.  What is the expected number of distinct lottery tickets purchased?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability that a particular ticket is not bought by anyone is $(1-1/N)^M$ (where $N$ is the number of different tickets, and $M$ is the number of tickets bought).  So the probability that a particular ticket *is* bought (by someone) is $1-(1-1/N)^M$; and the expected number of distinct tickets that are bought is
$$
N\cdot\left(1-(1-1/N)^M\right)=N-N(1-1/N)^M.
$$
When $M$ and $N$ are both large, this is approximately $N-Ne^{-M/N}=N(1-e^{-M/N}).$  In particular, if $M\gg N$, it's about $N$; if $M \ll N$, it's about $M$; and otherwise it's somewhere in between.  In your case, $M/N=1/6$, and so about $N(1-e^{-1/6})$ or $46$ million distinct tickets are bought.